# Find a new PDF by transforming a variable

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a PDF $$
f_X(x) = \frac{1}{4}(x+1), \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 < x < 2 
$$
I would like to use $$Z = \frac{9}{(X+1)^2}$$ and find a new PDF.

Since, $z = g(x) = 9/(x+1)^2$ is monotone increasing, I thought I can use the following formula ($X$ has pdf $f_X(x)$ and let $Y=g(X)$) $$
 f_Y(y) =\begin{cases} f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y) \right| & y \in \mathcal{Y} \\ 0  & otherwise \end{cases} 
$$

What I got is:
$$
f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{9}{(z+1)^2} + 1 \right) \cdot \left| \frac{-9\cdot2(x+1)}{\left\{ ((z+1)^2 \right\}^2} \right|
$$
But it seems it's quite different from the answer, $f_Z(z) = 9/(8z^2),\ 1<z<9$. What is wrong with my calculation?

Comment: The inverse should be $g^{-1}(y)=\frac{3}{\sqrt{y}}-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the @user375366 's help, I could get the correct answer. I spell out my calculation for future reference.

- Calculate $g^{-1}(z)$
  $$
  z = \frac{9}{(x+1)^2} \\
   \Longleftrightarrow  \frac{9}{z} = (x + 1)^2\\
   \Longleftrightarrow x = \frac{3}{\sqrt{z}}-1 
  $$
  Hence, $$f_X(g^{-1}(z)) = \frac{1}{4}\frac{3}{\sqrt{z}}.$$
- Calculate $\left|\frac{d}{dz}g^{-1}(z) \right|$
  $$
  \left| \left(\frac{3}{z^{\frac{1}{2}}}-1 \right)^{'} \right| = \left| - \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{z^3}}\right|
  $$

These results give $$f_Z(z) = \frac{9}{8z^2}$$